# List of best LaTex Editors in 2020

Tags: sourcecode

There are plenty of people who still raise this concern, Since I too use such editors, I’ve compiled this list of best LaTex editors  with good facilities and features. Here are the top ones that I could recommend:

1. TEXMAKER

Website: https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/

2. TEXSTUDIO

Website: http://www.texstudio.org

3. LYX

Website: https://www.lyx.org

4. TEXWORKS

Website: https://www.tug.org/texworks/

5. TEXNIC

Website: http://www.texniccenter.org/texnic

6. LED

Website: https://www.latexeditor.org

Source: https://techshali.com/latex-editors/

I hope this information helps you.

Cheers!!

Comment: You should mention the OS.

Comment: This is not a question, and this is a site for questions & answers.

Comment: only post questions in the question box.

Comment: I agree this is not a question. And it depends a whole lot on what else the coder does. ATOM is a fantastic editor, not a dedicated LaTex one and can do almost anything with the right plugins. Someone whose only coding is done in LaTex will make very different choices.